# how to get one of value from multple array

Tags: javascript

I have several elements with this class: `text-muted text-right`. These elements have differents `innerText` properties. I want to get only one of them:

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBXk7.png)

`22/11/2022 17:35:41` I want to get only that value

Comment: This problem is solvable, but no one can help you solve it until you provide a [mre]. Also, please post actual code, not images of code. See [ask].

Comment: you can use `const result = eben.find(item => item.innerText === '22/11/2022 17:35:41');`

Comment: @Amaarockz We both answered at the same time -.-

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const found = eben.find(element => element.innerText === '22/11/2022 17:35:41')
```

Comment: thank you so much , but there one problem date value will be change every time its not statick. for examaple todays value will bbe 25/11/22

Comment: @miraçreisoğlu after selecting the element you can put this afterwards: 

el.innerText = new Date().toDateString()